Unable to use knative with GKE ingress
I am currently checking how to do the following:
I want to deploy an app on a Google Kubernetes Engine.
This app runs perfectly fine.
Now I want to deploy it via knative with net-kourier.
The Service used for Kourier is set to 'ClusterIP'.
Now I want to set up an ingress (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/load-balance-ingress#create-ingress) to talk to the app. (Background information: I want to use Identity Aware Proxy for auth reasons).
But that does not seem to work with knative.
Can somehow give some hints on how to proceed?
Thanks :)
My knative service:
apiVersion: serving.knative.dev/v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: apps
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "my-backendconfig"}' # Uses IAP: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#associating_backendconfig_with_your_ingress
        cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: my-image

Backendconfig:
---
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
  namespace: apps
spec:
  iap:
    enabled: true
    oauthclientCredentials:
      secretName: iap-credentials


Ingress:
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: apps-ingress
  namespace: apps
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: my-frontendconfig
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-static-ip
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: my-cert
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: my-app
                port:
                  number: 80
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific


